# bootstrap-datetimepicker hours and minutes not defaulted to 00:00

Tags: javascript

how to set default time hours and minutes as 00:00 but if i pick hours and minutes picked value should come. My issue is current time is coming by default and current date is highlighting. i am using bootstrap date time picker

By using option i am changing like this but not working. if i change format like dd/mm/yyyy 00:00 all the time it is showing 00:00 even if i pick hours and minutes. pls help me to solve this issue

My code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({      
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker("setHours",'00' );
    });
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({  
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker("setMinutes",'00' );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try initializing the date picker with a default date, instead of trying to explicitly set the values. (I'm not sure datetimepicker even has setHours/minutes methods.) For example, you might do something like:

```
var d = new Date();
// hours, minutes, seconds 
d.setHours(0, 0, 0);

$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: d
});
```

Hopefully this works for you or at least points you in the right direction! :)

Answer (score 0):

What's jquery you using? Is it [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) ?

You should try to use [DateTimePicker jQuery](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/). It's simple and very good.

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      format : 'd/m/Y H:i',
      defaultTime:'00:00',
      formatTime:'H:i'
});
```

Comment: above two code also not working. i think i have to change in css file. by using option if i change it is not reflecting

Comment: You should try again.I just test my code.It works normal

Comment: d/m/Y H:i this value only coming in text box